# LDAP Session persistence

Tags: java, obiee

I have a scenario which requires a solution in java. 
Scenario: We have our employee portal which is authenticated through LDAP. Portal provides access to a OBIEE dashboard, a different website which also authenticates using LDAP. So, when the user clicks on the OBIEE dashboard link in employee portal, he will be directed to a OBIEE login page where he has to login again using same credentials. However I would like to directly login into the OBIEE dashboard because user has already logged in successfully into the employee portal.
Please help

Comment: You probably can use Single Sign On, using a SSO provider. For more details, search "SSO and OBIEE" which will give a an insight on what needs to be done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have enabled SSO in our BI Portal. But when I try to login directly using the Dashboard Link it is not enabling us to do so. We are getting an error "You are not currently logged in into Oracle BI Server".  We want the original functionality of BI dashboard to be retained i.e., if user is not authenticating through portal and instead directly trying to access the dashboard page he should be asked to login.Can we do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the same authentication source for both the java portal and OBIEE 11g after enabling SSO